# Doing explicit binding throws me an error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do an explicit binding in my Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php . When i do it as it is written in documentation i get an error with showing an incorrect path to my model. but adding .. before my path does not work as it is not a string and just adds one more error.

```
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();

        Route::model('post', App\Post::class);
    }
```

I get an error with incorrect path to the model:

```
Class App\Providers\App\Post does not exist
```

It tries to find the path within the providers folder..
But the documentation example showing just that , example from the documentation:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('user', App\User::class);
}
```

I suspect that it is because it is within namespace App\Providers ,but dont know what should i do.  Thank you.

Whole service provider class here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();

        Route::model('post', \App\Post::class);
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

And my Post model class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{

        /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'content','user_id'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'date',
    'updated_at' => 'date'
];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id'
    ];


    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Comment: What about `\App\Post::class` ?

Comment: @Chay22 It does exit in `App` folder and has `namespace App;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution prefix with `\` so that the namespace starts from the root and not the current one.

`Route::model('post', \App\Post::class);`

Other solution import the class at the top :

```
<?php

use App\Post;

...

    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();

        Route::model('post', Post::class);
    }
...
```

Comment: I tried both ways with importing the model at the top and adding ` \   ` ,but it throws me an error `Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Post does not exist`

Comment: Please add the code of your entire file in your question

Comment: @MantasValuckas That means the error in Provider is gone. And now you have to fix syntax importing within your controller.

Comment: Indeed, you now need to update your controller, use `\App\Post` instead of `App\Post`

Comment: @SimonDepelchin in what way do i update my controller , sorry if what im asking seems stupid, im pretty new to this framefork. I added `\App\Post` instead in my Provider

Comment: The new error you are having happens in one of your controller. You need to find it and apply the same changes you did on your provider, probably change `App\Post` to `\App\Post`.